# Hosting RESTful API on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, rest, heroku

I am relatively new to this Heroku and I am not sure if Heroku is right for my requirement mentioned below:
My requirement:

1. I've made a very basic Python app - which reads google spreadsheets and store the results in a database.
2. I've made another basic RESTful API which will be invoked to get the results calculated by the Python app.

My questions:

1. Can I host a RESTful API on Heroku for free? I will be invoking the API less than 10 times per month.
2. Does Heroku support me with a database to store some 5000 records with 5-10 columns?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627), and please make sure that your question is on-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: For your first question, please take a look at [Heroku's pricing page](https://www.heroku.com/pricing). For the second, please [decide what kind of database you want](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) and check _its_ pricing page. 5,000 records with 5-10 columns is quite small, so you'll probably be fine with the cheapest / free tiers for most of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can I host a RESTful API on Heroku for free? I will be invoking the API less than 10 times per month.

**Yes.**

2. Does Heroku support me with a database to store some 5000 records with 5-10 columns?

**I tested up to 940 records, no more.**